# Salesforce+DocuSign: how to autopopulate the recipient of my envelope via DocuSign with the record contacts?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, docusignapi, apex

I'm working on Salesforce, and I'm customizing the Quote object. The dafault button "Send with DocuSign" is already on the Quote layout. I'd like to populate the recipient of the DocuSign envelope with the contact(s) of the respective Quote.

Is there an easy way to this, or should I create a new Lightning Component with a button and build a whole new code?

Answer (score 0):

The org i work in doesnt use lighnigh so can't help you there but I considered implementing this in classic (but didn't). Below may help you.

[Docusign Support - Docusign Javascript Template](https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-sample-js-code-custom-buttons)

With the above template you can create your own javascript docusign button.

The variable that passes contact information to Docusign is the CRLC variable (found in the template above).

[Docusign Support - Customising Contacts](https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-customize-envelope-contacts) <- more info here.

to map the fields in the javascript button you will need to have a Contact lookup field on the quote(one for every recipient).

- Employee selects a contact and populates the lookup
- Javascript button uses the relationship field to get the variables from the contact.4

  > > FirstName~contact_lookup__r.first_name

I dont think this is too much work. as long as your comfortable completing the template or adding the CRL variable to your own docusign.